# Type codes in python (for array)

Tags: python

So following is the list of type codes in python:

```
Code       Python Type           Min bytes
'b'                int                   1
'B'                int                   1
'u'            unicode                   2
'h'                int                   2
'H'                int                   2
'i'                int                   2
'I'                int                   2
'l'                int                   4
'L'                int                   4
'f'              float                   4
'd'              float                   8
```

Question is, how do I know which code type to use when declaring a array in python? 
Lets say there is this code:
Now how was it decided that the data type would be 'd'. It does represent 'float'. But so does 'f'.
Similarly 'b' represents 'int' but so does 'B'.
What is the difference?
Thank you.

```
import array as arr

a = arr.array('d', [1.1, 3.5, 4.5])

print(a)
```

Comment: 'f' and 'd' look like they are different sizes

Comment: There are a couple of [missing columns](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#module-array) in your table, the answer to your question is there.

Comment: What do you mean how to decide? you decide based on the fixed-size numeric type you require. Honestly, if you are asking this, you almost certainly don't want to use the `array.array` object, why are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a good control over data types, then use Numpy library instead of the built-in Array library.
See https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html

However, if you must use "array", then here are your choices for floating point numbers:

```
'f' float 4 bytes 
'd' double 8 bytes
```

Basically 'd' is a double precision floating point version of 'f'.  You can represent floating point numbers with many more decimal point accuracy with the 'd' double floating point type.  A four byte number can represent 2^32 = 4 294 967 296 units. An eight byte number can represent 2^64 units.

Likewise, 'b' and 'B' are two different integer number types.

```
'b' signed char int 1 byte (does NOT have + or - sign)  
'B' unsigned char int 1 byte  (has + or - sign)
```

Since both are only a single byte, they represent a short integer. You can represent 0 to 255 decimal numbers with one unsigned byte. You can represent -128 to +127 with one signed byte.

See docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html
http://artsites.ucsc.edu/ems/music/equipment/computers/bits_bytes/bits_bytes.html

You choose the data type based on your data.  For casual programming while learning Python, 'b' signed int and 'f' 4 bytes floating point number types are good choices.  Double precision 'd' is also commonly used in instructional videos.  This is fine if you are working with a small dataset and a modern computer that has enough memory to handle the data size.

Answer corrected to reflect that capital B is "un"signed.  I had it flipped with small b.  Sorry.

Comment: no ... 'B' is unsigned char and 'b' is signed char. Just look in the "See docs:" link above please.

Comment: Thanks Aendie, I corrected with capital B being unsigned.